# Force 4k display mode on Android with preferedDisplayMode

Tags: android

I am trying to force 4k display mode to target phones with 4k screens. It was working pretty well with Android M and I had beautiful 4k support using

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.preferredDisplayModeId = 2;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

After the Android N update it changed the behavior completely, the whole interface gets scaled way over the screen limits where I only see a portion of the screen, including the status bar and the navigation buttons on the bottom. to leave the app I need to close it from Android Studio.

Any idea how to get the Android M behavior back?